# How can I loop into a hash of hashes of arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, cvs, perl-data-structures

i'm trying to do a script to download my CVS modules and his respectives dependencies, I organized the projects into a hash on my Perl script:

```
$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;

$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => ('module1', 'module2'),
        'repository2' => ('module3', 'module4', 'module5'),
        'repository3' => ('module6', 'module7')
    }
};

if ($num_args <= 2) {
    print "($num_args) Insufficient arguments!\n";
    print "Usage: cp-stack.pl PRODUCT_NAME USER [PASSWORD [BRANCH]]\n";
    exit;
}

$Product = $ARGV[0];
$User = $ARGV[1];
$Password = '';
$Branch = '';

if ($num_args >= 3) {
    $Password = $ARGV[2];
}
if ($num_args >= 4) {
    $Branch = $ARGV[3];
}
$productFound = 0;

for my $firstKey (keys %$products) {
    my $productName = $firstKey;
    my $productHash = $products{$productName};
    print "$productName\n";
    if ($productName == $Product) {
        $productFound = 1;
        print "Product '$productName' found!\n";
        print $products{$productName} . " keys\n";
        for my $secondKey (keys %{ $productHash }) {
        #while (my($repository, $modulesList) = each(%$productHash)) {
            my $repository = $secondKey;
            my $modulesList = $productHash{$repository};
            printf("set CVSROOT=:pserver:$User\@mycvsaddr.com:/cvsdirectory/$repository\n");
            for my $i (0 .. $#modulesList) {
                if ($Branch != '') {
                    printf("cvs checkout -P -r {$Branch} " . $modulesList[$i] . "\n");
                } else {
                    printf("cvs checkout -P " . $modulesList[$i] . "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It ran into Product 'name' found! But don't enter in the modules loop... I can't figure it out why.

I'm a begginer in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'repository1' => ('module1', 'module2'),
'repository2' => ('module3', 'module4', 'module5'),
'repository3' => ('module6', 'module7')
```

is the same as

```
'repository1', 'module1', 'module2', 'repository2', 'module3',
'module4', 'module5', 'repository3', 'module6', 'module7'
```

so

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => ('module1', 'module2'),
        'repository2' => ('module3', 'module4', 'module5'),
        'repository3' => ('module6', 'module7')
    }
};
```

is a weird way of writing

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => 'module1',
        'module2'     => 'repository2',
        'module3'     => 'module4',
        'module5'     => 'repository3',
        'module6'     => 'module7',
    }
};
```

You never create any arrays! You can create anonymous arrays using square brackets.

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => [ 'module1', 'module2' ],
        'repository2' => [ 'module3', 'module4', 'module5' ],
        'repository3' => [ 'module6', 'module7' ],
    }
};
```

Just like `{ }` returns a reference to the hash, `[ ]` returns an reference to the array. So

```
for my $i (0 .. $#modulesList) {
    ... $modulesList[$i] ...
}
```

needs to be

```
for my $i (0 .. $#$modulesList) {
    ... $modulesList->[$i] ...
}
```

or

```
for my $module (@$modulesList) {
    ... $module ...
}
```

Comment: I still can't iterate into the array of modules. Don't know why :-(
But the repositories loop now works fine!

Comment: I forgot to use the
    $#$modulesList instead of $#modulesList
worked fine now! Thanks!

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! `my $modulesList = $productHash{$repository};` should be `my $modulesList = $productHash->{$repository};`

Answer (score 1):

That's not a hash of hash of arrays.

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => ('module1', 'module2'),
        'repository2' => ('module3', 'module4', 'module5'),
        'repository3' => ('module6', 'module7')
    }
};
```

Flattens to

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => 'module1',
        'module2' => 'repository2',
        'module3' => 'module4',
        'module5' => 'repository3',
        'module6', 'module7',
    }
};
```

You need to be defining your arrays with arrayrefs: `[]`

```
$products = {
    'productName' => {
        'repository1' => ['module1', 'module2'],
        'repository2' => ['module3', 'module4', 'module5'],
        'repository3' => ['module6', 'module7']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive descent through a hash hierarchy is a different thing from the particulars of what you need to process at each node. One is generic to descending hashes, the other specific to what you want to do with the data structure.

- First you need descent logic
- And, then you need a node handler.

This is roughly my basic hash descender:

```
use Carp qw<croak>;
use Params::Util qw<_ARRAY _CODE _HASH _HASH0>;

sub  hash_descend (+@);

sub hash_descend (+@) { 
    croak ( 'Hash value or reference missing' ) 
        # I use _HASH0 here, because I don't really want to yell at the user
        # for simply providing an empty set. 
        unless _HASH0( my $h = shift )
        ;

    return unless %$h;

    # also set it up so that it can return tuples of key-paths and values
    # [ k_1, k_2, ... , k_n => v ]
    my @accum;
    my $block = _CODE( $_[0] ) ? shift : sub { push @accum, [ @_ ] };

    while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each $h ) { 
        local $_ = $v;
        $block->( @_, $k, $v );
        if ( _HASH( $v )) { 
            hash_descend( $v, $block, @_, $k );
        }
    }
    return unless @accum;
    return @accum;
}
```

- Note that as it is recursive, I forward-declare it
- I also use the new style prototype which turns hashes and arrays into refs of that type.
- The second parameter allows a callback to play with each node.
- I "contextualize" the value for briefer callback expressions.

Once I'm done with that, I write the logic for handling nodes. I wanted to optimize some of the needless if logic you're doing in a loop, so I came up with this:

```
my $branch_arg  = $Branch ? "-r $Branch " : '';
my $command_fmt = "cvs checkout -P $branch_arg%s";

hash_descend( $products => sub { 
    return unless my $arr = _ARRAY( $_[-1] );
    foreach ( @$arr ) { 
        say sprintf( $command_fmt, $_ );
    }
});
```